Kysely ColumnType Insert Type Compilation Error
I used kysely-codegen and it spit out something like the following:
export type Int8 = ColumnType<
  string,
  bigint | number | string,
  bigint | number | string
>;

export interface UserTable {
  ...
  phoneOneCountryId: Generated<Int8>;
 ...
}

I think codegen did Generated around the column because it has a default value?
Which I then wrap:
export type NewUser = Insertable<UserTable>;
However when I go to use like so:
const testNewUser: NewUser = {
      ...
      phoneOneCountryId: 20,
      ...
    };

I get compilation error:
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Int8'.ts(2322)

If I understand how codegen set up Int8 correctly with ColumnType then it passed
bigint | number | string,
as the InsertType (middle arg). So I wouldn't expect this to error - what am I missing here?

Ended up figuring it out through combing through kysely-codegen closed issues that there is a differnece between the out-of-the-box kysely Generated type and the Generated type I was removing (that I thought was extra) that gets generated with codegen. When I restored for the codegen one the compilation issue went away.
Relevant kysely-codegen issue explaining: https://github.com/RobinBlomberg/kysely-codegen/issues/88#issuecomment-1669086576
For reference current codegen type:
export type Generated<T> = T extends ColumnType<infer S, infer I, infer U>
  ? ColumnType<S, I | undefined, U>
  : ColumnType<T, T | undefined, T>;
```

Versus current kysely:
export type Generated<S> = ColumnType<S, S | undefined, S>;

